# How does del.icio.us know what tags to suggest for a URL?

Tags: tagging, autosuggest

When I bookmark http://dbpedia.org/About, del.icio.us suggests "xml" and "programming" as tags. How does it know that the URL relates to these topics?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is most likely because other users have tagged that same URL with those tags.

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely based on other users. More "unknown" pages won't have any suggestions, but popular pages that others have presumably bookmarked will have them.

Answer (score 1):

Probably watches for other persons' tags, although I would have wanted it to crawl the URL pages and process its suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

it's still based on other users. but i think, if they want stay one of the most used plattforms, they should add another tagging techniques. there are some great ideas in that field - Faviki (based on Wikipedia) or Meaning of a Tag (MOAT).